# azure data factory get lookup activity error output

Tags: azure-data-factory

Im my pipeline, there is only one lookup activity and a stored procedure activity following it when the lookup fails.

The lookup sends a query like

```
    select 1/count(*) as result from sometable
```

The stored procedure activity calls a stored precedure with a parameter named 'error'.

Basically I want this lookup to fail when count(*) is 0, and then I want to capture the divide by 0 error message from the activity output and use that as the input parameter for the stored procedure.

The output from the lookup when count(*) is 0 is:

```
    {
        "errorCode": "2100",
        "message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorFailedFileOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Upload file failed at path 37b1ec96-be95-4010-8547-10387fc407a3\\result.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Divide by zero error encountered.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=8134,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=8134,State=1,Message=Divide by zero error encountered.,},],'",
        "failureType": "UserError",
        "target": "Lookup source count",
        "details": []
    }
```

So in the stored procedure activity, I want to put the message from above to the parameter of the stored procedure. I have tried @activity('Lookup source count').output.message for the input parameter. But get this error:

```
    {
        "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
        "message": "The expression 'activity('Lookup source count').output.message' cannot be evaluated because property 'message' doesn't exist, available properties are ''.",
        "failureType": "UserError",
        "target": "log fail Lookup source count",
        "details": ""
    }
```

I have also tried many other options but none of them works. How can I get the error message from the lookup when it fails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using, "Add dynamic content", use this as your SP parameter value

`@activity('<name of your lookup>').Error.Message`

Comment: Is there any document for this? I googled a lot but couldn't find any on this.

Comment: I think I found it through googling but you are 100% right, there are a lot of magic incantations that are not googled. The other way is to inspect the output in the monitor and you can see that the output json is in that form

Comment: Yeah I can't find it on google I must have done it by trial and error and inspecting the output.

Comment: This is the documentation for this kind of expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions

Comment: That is certainly a guide on the expression syntax but there are no clues on how to capture activity outputs.

Comment: Here's another bunch of handy references. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6320/logging-azure-data-factory-pipeline-audit-data/ I found this while trying to work out why `@activity('<copy activity>').output` is null after a copy activity failure. The error message would be nice to capture.

Comment: This https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7e59de13-ef78-49f0-aa4f-bc57b6d83aad/adf-v2-email-notification-web-activity-how-to-catch-error-message-for-a-copy-activity?forum=AzureDataFactory incorrectly states that `@{activity('Copy 1').output.errors}` should catch errors - it doesn't. Or maybe it did and they changed it

Comment: On my side this works but only if there is an error, otherwise I get 
`Error.Message cannot be evaluated because property 'Message' cannot be selected.`